# Where should I put the .pem files for ApnsPHP to work?

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have my two files `entrust_root_certification_authority.pem` and `server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem`, but I'm not sure where I should put them. I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ApnsPHP_Exception' with message 'Unable to read certificate file 'server_cerificates_bundle_sandbox.pem''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example contains an error, the name of file in sample_push.php is wrong 'server_cerificates_bundle_sandbox.pem', correct name is 'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'. Only for tests, you can put pem files in root directory of your apns site. I had the same problem, but now it works fine.

Good luck.

Comment: What about for production where I put this file. Also, please could you answer my question on "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501588/cant-get-ios-push-notification-on-server" that is related to this question