# Can't get iOS push notification on server

Tags: php, ios, linux, push-notification, cpanel

This is a screenshot of file manager on my shared server. I will use [ApnsPHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) to send push notifications, but I am beginner in  web developing. so, sorry for my questions.

- Where Can upload [ApnsPHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) files, so only iOS app can use it. And what is the URL that will be used in the app?
- Where can upload xxx.pem file, so it can't be downloaded by others. And what is its URL that will be used in other php files?
- How to run xxxx.php in background on shared server, because there is some file of [ApnsPHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) needs to be run in background forever?
- How to create environment variable on shared server?

Thanks in advance, and appreciate any help

[image: fsdafasfsdsdasd]

Comment: You should maybe look into Urban Airship if you don't want to go through this hassle.

Comment: I agree, chances are you won't be hitting Urban Airship's free push notification cap anytime soon. If you're asking a lot of basic server questions then Urban Airship makes even more sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but ApnsPHP is the target.

Comment: Not really. You have to pay for the new dev accounts.